# lossy conversion when dividing (long to int)

Tags: java, arrays, quicksort

I am trying to find the middle index in an array (of type long)
The problem im solving specifically asks for a long to return, so I cant change the signature
I want to find the pivot point, in my quicksort code, but I get an error "possible lossy conversion from long to int"
I understand that I may lose some information when dividing, but I want to bypass it
here is the code containing the error:

```
public static long partition(long[] array, long left, long right){
    long i = left, j = right;
    long tmp;
    long pivot = array[(left + right) / 2];  // <-----ERROR HERE  <------

    while(i <= j) {
        while(array[i] < pivot){
        i--;
       }
       while(array[j] > pivot) {
           j--;
       }
       if(i <= j) {
           tmp =array[i];
           array[i] = array[j];
           array[j] = tmp;
           i++;
           j--;
       }
       }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: an array has indices of type `int`

Comment: try array[(left + right) / 2L];

Comment: @lakshman that makes no difference, the 2 would undergo binary numeric promotion to long already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "array[index]", this "index" must be int. so

```
long pivot = array[(int)((left + right) / 2)];
```

Answer (score 3):

From [JLS Sec 10.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4):

> Arrays must be indexed by int values

Using `long` for the `left` and `right` parameters (and `i` and `j`) is meaningless (because an array can't have that many elements), and will result in a compile-time error. Change them to `int`.

Answer (score -1):

I tried typecasting the long to int like..
**long pivot = array[(int) ((left + right) / 2)];**
It works for me, can you please elaborate in which scenario you are getting the error "possible lossy conversion from long to int".

Comment: [Please format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)